# Cannot import Objective-C code into Swift file

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase

I would like to import an objective c code from TwitterAuthHelper.h file into my swift code.

After that i added the header file to my project, i created the Bridging Header file that i defined " #import "TwitterAuthHelper.h" " inside of it.

[The Bridging file that i added ' #import "TwitterAuthHelper.h" '](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXNvA.png)

However, when i wanted to use TwitterAuthHelper(firebaseRef: .... inside that swift file, it says "use of unresolved identifier 'TwitterAuthHelper'", even though i defined the import of header file inside of the Bridging Header file.

[The Swift file that i would like to import the objective C code into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdJgF.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had some experience with this you should make sure that you named your bringing-header file correctly. You also my clean your build and then build it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i fixed it!

Comment: How did you do it so others with the same question can. 

Comment: I actually did it by the way you explained. I deleted the Bridging header file and created it again, but this time i checked the name whether is correct from Project / Build Settings / Swift Compiler - Code Generation / Objective-C Bridging Header / ....
This time it did not give any error.

Comment: That is great would you mind hitting the little ✅ below my answer to accept it as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

i'm fix this

insert `#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>`

in file `TwitterAuthHelper.h` and clean the project.